# c++ compile error/ syntax error? reason for error unknown

Tags: visual-c++

So I honestly have no idea what's wrong with my code. Any suggestions would help. Look at the section of the code where I comment(towards the middle). the computer gives me an error saying expected a";". Something is wrong with the bracket or i screwed up some where else and just can't find it.

```
//Experiment2
//Creating functions and recalling them.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void a()
{
cout<<"You try running but trip and fall and the crazy man kills you!!!!                     HAAHAHAHHAHA.";
}


void b()
{
cout<<"You stop drop and roll and the crazy man is confused by this and leaves you alone!";
}

void c()
{
cout<<"you try fighting the man but end up losing sorry!";
}




int main()
{
int a;
int b;
int c;
int d;
a=1;
b=2;
c=3;

cout<< "Once upon a time you was walking to school,\n";
cout<< " when all of the sudden some crazy guy comes running at you!!!!"<<endl;
cout<< " (This is the begining of your interactive story)"<<endl;
cout<< "Enter in the number according to what you want to do.\n";
cout<< " 1: run away, 2:stop drop and roll, or 3: fight the man."<<endl;
cin>>d;
void checkd()
//i dont know whats wrong with the bracket! the computer gives me an error saying expected a";"
{
    if(d==1)

    {
        void a();
    }

    if(d==2)

    {
        void b();
    }

    if(d==3)

    {
        void c();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define a function within another function. You defined a function `checkd()` inside the `main` function.

Move the function body outside the `main` and just call the function from `main` as:

```
checkd(d);
```

Probably, You also want the function to take an parameter which it needs to compare.

Also,

```
void a();
```

does not call the function `a()` it just declares the function, to call the function you need:

```
a();
```

---

```
void checkd(int d)

{
    if(d==1)

    {
        a();
    }

    if(d==2)

    {
        b();
    }

    if(d==3)
    {
        c();
    }
}
int main()
{
    ....
    ....
    cout<< " 1: run away, 2:stop drop and roll, or 3: fight the man."<<endl;
    cin>>d;
    checkd();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Constantinius: The function doesn't take a parameter, but it should.